# Single computer crashes network and has very high upload rates to specific ip

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu pc which I use as a mere minecraft server. However a few hours ago it started preventing me or any device connected to the network to use internet. I also noticed it has a constant huge upload rate to a specific chinese IP(I don't know if I can post it here, so for now I won't). If I disconnect the ethernet cable everything goes back to normal. It is NOT a hardware issue, since I have plugged the hard drive to an another computer and it behaves the same.

I tried nethogs to see which process is using that much bandwidth but it seems like nethogs will hang up and won't work. Also the local port changes continuously, so I can't track it from the port. The remote port is always 443.

Should I simply block the IP or maybe I should check first if the computer is infected (even if it is linux)?

Comment: The only sure solution is to wipe and rebuild the machine.

Comment: Try `lsof` to find out which process causes it, if removing malicious program won't help, disconnect it from net and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

It appears your machine has been hacked.

Rebuilding the machine without understanding how it got hacked will just make this happen again.

Before rebuilding the machine, see how you can "harden" your machine:

- No passwords, only SSH keys allowed
- Firewall (`ufw` is a human-understandable firewall) to block all the ports, beside the very few necessary (HTTP/HTTPS/SSH)(and possibly only allow SSH from known addresses, or rate-limit everybody)
- Something like `fail2ban` to detect and ban IPs doing brute force attack
- Other measures depending on installed software, such as having good passwords on administration consoles (phpMyAdmin, etc...), and putting them on non-standard and random URLs.